# npm run deploy error unable to publish on github pages

Tags: reactjs, github, npm, github-pages

I've had my personal website made with React published on Github pages for about a year now and I would always update it using the following commands:

```
git add .
git commit -m "update"
npm run deploy
git push -u origin main
```

The last time I was able to run these commands without fail was last week. Since then, the only changes I've done to the repo are changing the repo name on Github but now I'm unable to run the same commands without receiving a 403 error. In the end I decided to start a new repo but now I get the following error:

```
fatal: A branch named 'gh-pages' already exists.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! username.github.io@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the username.github.io@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/computer/.npm/_logs/2021-08-17T22_31_00_085Z-debug.log
```

I've also tried manually removing gh-pages from node_modules/.cache but instead I get this error:

```
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/username/username.github.io.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! username.github.io@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the username.github.io@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/username/.npm/_logs/2021-08-17T22_41_14_919Z-debug.log
```

Is there anything else I can do besides give up?

*** note: I replaced my actual gh username for privacy

Comment: For the last problem, it looks like you have to follow this link: https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for a solution.  The error message states that you have to use a personal access token instead of password authentication.